# Microsoft.Services.Tools.BizTalkDocumenter.Setupv5.1.7.1 is not documenting few orchestration

Tags: biztalk

We used Microsoft.Services.Tools.BizTalkDocumenter.Setupv5.1.7.1.msi to document the deployed orchestration in our server. But few orchestrations are not documented in .chm file. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: No, it should document all Orchestrations in the selected Applications.  Can you please add any details of this issue to https://biztalk2013documenter.codeplex.com/workitem/2012

Comment: my colleague had already placed that question on that link.In terms details one thing i want to specify is that orchestration is too big...is that maybe one of the reason its not able to create CHM file?? because when i tried to debug your code on local out of 100 orchestration it not even able to create CHM for 50% of the orchestrations...throwing random exceptions

Comment: Your colleague did not respond to our request for more details as how to reproduce the issue.  So adding some details like the fact that it seems to be large Orchestrations (e.g. number of shapes) and the exception thrown would be useful.

Comment: Orchestration Details -
Variables - 40
Messages- 30
Shapes - 170+(Approx)

It doesn't throw any exception while executing the exe..it just simply skip that orchestration and doesn't provide the process overview and code elements.It only provide the document related to variable messages.

Comment: Exception while downloading your code through SVN - Unable to connect to repository url.XML response contain invalid XML

Comment: Code Exception while Debugging -
1) List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified
2)System.Invalid.Operation Exception
3)Object reference is not set to an instance of an object
These are not consistent..randomly occurring while i am trying to generate the CHM document